# left join of 3 tables according to one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of Filters, and a many-to-many table named FilterDoctors , that relates doctors according to which the filter should be made.

I want to return the Id of all the filters that **either**:

1. Has no doctors filter (FilterDoctors.DoctorId IS NULL)
   **OR:**
2. Has a doctor that is related to the incident with id = @IncidentId
   **OR:**
3. Has a doctor that is related to an appointment that its related incident's id = @IncidentId

I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT Filters.filterId
FROM Filters
  Left JOIN FilterDoctors   On FilterDoctors.filterId = Filters.filterId 
  Left JOIN IncidentDoctors On IncidentDoctors.doctorId = FilterDoctors.DoctorId
  Left JOIN Appointments    On Appointments.doctorId = FilterDoctors.DoctorId
Where ( IncidentDoctors.IncidentId = @IncidentId
        OR Appointment.RelatedIncidentId = @IncidentId
        OR FilterDoctors.DoctorId IS NULL)
```

Unfortunately, this query doesn't seem to work, since the same filterId is returned several times.
I checked and the result of the join has Appointment records with doctors that exists in the doctor filter , but aren't related to the incident with id = @IncidentId as I wanted.

> **The tables relationships  are:**
>
> Appointments  N : 1  Incidents
>
> Doctors       N : 1  Incidents
>
> Doctors       1 : N  Appointments
>
> Filters       N : N  Doctors

What should be the right query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's with following:

```
SELECT Filters.filterId
FROM Filters
  Left JOIN FilterDoctors   On FilterDoctors.filterId = Filters.filterId 
  Left JOIN IncidentDoctors On IncidentDoctors.doctorId = FilterDoctors.DoctorId
  Left JOIN Appointments    On ( Appointments.doctorId = FilterDoctors.DoctorId 
                                 AND Appointment.RelatedIncidentId = IncidentDoctors.IncidentId)
WHERE ( IncidentDoctors.IncidentId = @IncidentId
        OR FilterDoctors.DoctorId IS NULL)
GROUP BY Filters.filterId;
```

Comment: Perhaps a `DISTINCT` may still be required.